# File Upload as Category Attribute - Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute, setup-upgrade

I want to create a custom attribute for Category, which is File Attribute.

I want to upload any kind of documents in it.
Like PDF,txt, doc, etc,.

Anyone helps me to do that via setup Upgrade?

Same like this, in Magento 2

[Magento Custom Category Attribute File](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11926/magento-custom-category-attribute-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of the following blog.
Here There have tried to create a image category attribute, where us I tried with file PDF option.

https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-image-attribute-category-magento-2/

In Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml inside `allowedExtensions` I have added my file formats and I got success in that.